# Interactive input of integer-coordinate 2D points

Tags: graphics, manipulate, dynamic, locator

I'd like code to allow interactive input of a chain of 2D points, which are saved in some global variable. And in addition, I would like to constrain the coordinates to be integers.

The code below is my unskilled attempt. I have two questions, the first likely easy,
the second well beyond my expertise.

(1) The interactive input of points works nicely, but I do not see how to get the value stored in `pts` outside of the `Manipulate`.

(2) I've tried various mechanisms to constrain the coordinates to integers, e.g., using
`RegionNearest`, but I'm not even close to getting it working.

```
Manipulate[
 
 Graphics[{
   Point[pts]
   , {EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[Pink], Polygon[pts]}
   }, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
  , Axes -> True
  ](*Graphics*)
 
 , {
  {pts, {}}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> All
  }
 ]
```

Comment: for (2) try `DynamicModule[{pts = {}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
  Graphics[{Point[pts], {EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[Pink], 
     Polygon[pts]}}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
   Axes -> True], {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}, {1, 1}}, 
  LocatorAutoCreate -> All]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`LocatorPane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html) and

1. Use the second argument of `Dynamic` to update the global variable
2. Set the third argument of `LocatorPane` as `{{xmin, ymin},{xmax,ymax},{dx,dy}}` to specify the locator coordinates

```
loccoords = {};

Column[{DynamicModule[{pts = {}}, 
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, (pts = #; loccoords = #) &], 
    Dynamic @ Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pts], 
      EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[Pink], Polygon[pts]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, Axes -> True, 
     ImageSize -> Medium], {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}, {1, 1}}, 
    LocatorAutoCreate -> All, Appearance -> None]],
  Dynamic @ loccoords}]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[loccoords, PlotLabel -> Mean[loccoords]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice code! Well worth studying. Thanks so much!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, my pleasure.